# What does it mean for one to calculate an approximate value for $\mathcal{P}(t)$ for a given value of $t$, and how is it done?

Tags: markov-process, transition-matrix

Let's say we have some Markov process $(X(t): t \ge 0)$ with state space $S = \{ 1, 2, 3 \}$. Furthermore, let's say we're also given a generator matrix

$$Q = \begin{bmatrix} -1 & 0 & 1 \\ 4 & -5 & 1 \\ 1 & 8 & -9 \end{bmatrix}$$

Now define the one-step transition matrix to be $\mathcal{P}$. I was told that we can calculate an approximate value for $\mathcal{P}(t)$ for a given value of $t$. However, I don't understand exactly what this means, let alone how it is done. What does it mean for one to calculate an approximate value for $\mathcal{P}(t)$ for a given value of $t$, and how is it done?

Comment: This is not a valid generator matrix; row sums should be zero.

Comment: @E-A oops, sorry. It was just an example I was trying to conjure to understand the concept. I’ll fix it.

Comment: No worries; good to hear that you are not just copy pasting a question! Anyway, there is no need to approximate; $P(t)$ is precisely equal to $e^{tQ}$, which you can plug into WolframAlpha; you can use Taylor series for $e$ to approximate it of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The generator $Q$ is for a continuus-time process. The Matrix $P(t)$ is for a single discrete step of size $t$. They are related by the differential equation
$$ P'(t)=P(t)Q$$
with starting value $P(0)=I$ (the identity matrix). In order to see why this equation makes sense you should imagine a small time-increment $\delta t$ where you can assume that at most one transition takes place in the time $\delta t$.

Anyway, the solution of the differential equation is exactly
$$ P(t) = \exp(tQ)=I+tQ+\frac{1}{2}t^2Q^2+...$$
take as many terms as you like (or even compute it exactly. There are many methods of computing matrix exponentials)

edit: sry @E-A, your comment makes this answer unneccessary^^, I was too slow

Comment: Oh really nothing to apologize for; it is definitely better practice to write it as an answer (so it can be upvoted/downvoted); I just don't like taking responsibility and would spend too much time perfecting it (like writing out Kolmogorov Forward-Backward, and then thinking what conditions need to be imposed on Q etc.) I (and I am sure OP) definitely appreciate your answer!

Comment: @E-A Yes, I very much appreciate it! Thanks again, Simon! And thank you for the clarification, E-A!